# how to use jquery file only once in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mean

how to call the jquery file only once in my scenario

I am working in Mean Technology

I have a UI (working Html page). In that UI has header, footer, sidebar These header, footer, sidebar are coming from separate UI. I have combined to use in my Every html.

> this is the way to combine all html page and use it in my every page.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state" ng-controller="SlideController" ng-include="'slidebar.html'">
```

> in my side bar.html i have used this jquery

like this in my header.html also

```
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

> in originalUI.html (working Html page) also i have used

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

If I run my UI. this jquery will load 3 times. so some functionality not working at that time it return

```
jquery-2.1.4.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

if i removed that jquery in my header and sidebar. that not working functionality will work.

I don't know why. can anybody tell me how to resolve this problem

Comment: It is clear from error message that, Reference path of jquery file is wrong. And You need add reference to only one HTML. .i.e indext.html or main html file

Comment: @Ved in that path only i have kept the file.if i removed that jquery in my header and sidebar. that not working functionality will work.but side bar not working

Comment: You don't need multiple reference. Just include it on main html file

Comment: main html means working html?

Comment: Your root html file.

Comment: @ved we don't have any root html file. We are just loading another html as partial using ng-include.

Comment: So what. The html file where your are using `ng-include` must be your root html

Comment: @Ved I thought the same and Had removed in normal pages but then the working page jquery error is showing

Comment: @Ved I'm waiting for your reply

Comment: I don't know what approach you are following. What I can say is all refence should be added to main HTML only.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add jquery reference to starting HTML file(Eg:index.html,layout.html) of your app instead adding it to every file

Comment: Hi user1594, I have tried like that. but it is not working. it affects my sidebar funtionality